# Select minimum number of MySQL entries + entries with same data

Tags: php, mysql

I hope I can get some help with this, as I can't really figure it out myself :S.

I have a MySQL table, where I store soccer games. As it is now, I list the games on my site, with a date range.

First I find out if there is any unfinished games today...

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kampe WHERE dato = '$today' AND '$nu' < '$slut99' AND hiddenmatch = '0' ORDER BY tidspunkt");
```

Then I check for future games in the database...

```
mysql_query ("SELECT DISTINCT dato FROM kampe WHERE (dato > '$today' AND dato <= '$touger') AND hiddenmatch = '0' ORDER BY dato ASC");
```

So what I get listed is the games today, and then I get the rest of the games listed, grouped by date - witch is fine.

However, what I would like, is to have listed is the games today, and then minimum 20 (or whatever number I choose) games + if there is more games with the same date, as match number 20.

To try to simplify it - The games today are listed just fine - I do however want to list the following 20 games, but I don't want the list to be cut off in the middle of a date.

Comment: `mysql_query` is totally outdated. please go for mysqli: http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
    <FIELDS>
FROM 
    kampe 
WHERE 
    (dato > '$today' AND dato <= '$touger') AND 
    hiddenmatch = '0' 
ORDER BY 
    dato ASC
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    <FIELDS>
FROM 
    kampe 
WHERE 
    dato > '$today'
ORDER BY 
    dato ASC
LIMIT 20
```

NOTE : Keep the fields between both the table common

Hope this helps